# Execute query get result increment it by 1 and pass this as a variable in a xml payload

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter, I made a connection oracle and executing a query. 
For example select `employee_id` from `employee`

Result is **EMP100**

Now I want to increase the result by 1

> (e.g.  **EMP100** to **EMP101**)

and need capture new emp_is i,e EMP101 in a variable and use this variable in an another XML request.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have this `EMP100` in some [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${foo}` you can add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) and use the code like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String foo = vars.get("foo");

log.info("Original foo variable value: " + foo);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(foo);
if (m.find()) {
    String postfix = m.group(1);           
    int oldNumber = Integer.parseInt(postfix);
    oldNumber++;
    String newNumber = String.valueOf(oldNumber);
    foo = foo.replace(postfix, newNumber);
    vars.put("foo", foo);
}

log.info("New foo variable value: " + vars.get("foo"));
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Increment aplhanumeric variable]

After that you should be able to use the same `${foo}` variable in your XML payload or wherever else.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on enhancing your JMeter tests with scripting.